# How to exclude sticky element from scroll?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I want to exclude sticky div from filling out space on the site. It works as expected and sticks to the desired position.

[image]

HTML

```js
  <div v-if="isToastActive" class="toast">
    <span class="message">{{ messageRef }}</span>
  </div>
```

CSS

```css
.toast {
  position: sticky;
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0rem;
  max-width: fit-content;
  background-color: #22bb33;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

So my question is:

How can I exclude that sticky toast from scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: use `position: fixed`

Looks to me like you're trying to have that element stay on that place regardless of parent container, so try `position: fixed` instead of sticky

You normally use position sticky to keep an element stick at some bound of an smaller container within your body

when trying to have a position 'fixed' in some place inside your body, the better way is to go with position fixed